# Como fazer "Ao selecionar uma opção no dropdwn , ele carregue outros dados do banco em um Textarea" em php, mysql e Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, textarea, dinâmico

Tenho um form que tem um campo select `name="nome_cliente"` que recupera do banco de dados mysql todos clientes cadastrados.

nesse mesmo form tenho vários inputs que serão cadastrados para aquele cliente selecionado, e tem um textarea `name="evolucao"` que esta como readyonly porque nesse textarea quero que retorne do banco de dados a evolução já cadastrada desse cliente para quen estiver cadastrando informações novas ja saber o que tem cadastrado de evolução.

Gostaria de saber como faria isso, pois terá que ser com jquery a partir do `nome_cliente` que já foi selecionado no dropdown e carregar essas informações em um textarea.

Segue código

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-10 titulo">Adicionar sessões para Pacientes Cadastrados
</div>
<div id="adicionar">
 <form name="form1" action="<?php echo raiz?>servicosbd/adicionaragenda.php" method="POST">
  <div class="col-md-6 item">
   <div class="texto">
    Paciente:
   </div>
   <select name="nome_cliente" id="" required>
    <option value="">Escolha o paciente</option>
    <?php 
     
     $query = "select `id`,`nome` from `clientes` order by nome asc";
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);
     $num_results = $result->num_rows;
     if($num_results > 0){
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $id_cliente = $row['id'];
       $nome_cliente = $row['nome'];
       if(!empty($nome_cliente)){

    ?>

     <option value="<?php echo $nome_cliente; ?>"><?php echo $nome_cliente; ?></option>
    
    <?php
       }
      }
     }
    ?>
   </select>
   <?php if(!empty($id_cliente)){ ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" value="<?php echo $id_cliente; ?>">
   <?php } ?>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="texto">
    Evoluções Anteriores:
   </div>
   <textarea name="evolucao" rows="5" readonly style="background: #C1C1C1;color: #000000">
    
  AQUI QUE TEM QUE RETORNAR OS DADOS
     
    
   </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque em um atributo data o valor que você precisa de cada cliente e no change do input altere o valor do text area:

```
<select name="nome_cliente" id="" required>
<option value="">Escolha o paciente</option>
<?php
// ADICIONAR O CAMPO EVOLUCAO, ESTOU ADICINANDO UM EXEMPLO
$query = "select `id`,`nome`,`evolucao` from `clientes` order by nome asc";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
if ($num_results > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id_cliente = $row['id'];
        $nome_cliente = $row['nome'];
        // AQUI VOCÊ TERA QUE ADICIONAR A VARIAVEL EVOLUCAO E NA SUA QUERY TBM
        $evolucao = $row['evolucao'];
        if (!empty($nome_cliente)) {

            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $nome_cliente; ?>"
                    data-evolucao="<?php echo $evolucao ?>"><?php echo $nome_cliente; ?>>
            </option>

            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>
<!--Jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select[name="nome_cliente"]').on('change', function () {
            var evolucao = $('select[name="nome_cliente"] > option:selected').data('evolucao');

            $('textarea[name="evolucao"]').text(evolucao);
        });

    })
</script>
```

Deixei dos comentários no PHP onde você deverá adicionar o seu campo evolucao e vou colocar aqui embaixo um exemplo com dados estáticos para você ter uma idéia:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<select name="nome_cliente" id="" required>
    <option value="" data-evolucao="">Escolha o paciente</option>
    <option value="1" data-evolucao="Evolucao1">Paciente1</option>
    <option value="2" data-evolucao="Evolucao2">Paciente2</option>
    <option value="3" data-evolucao="Evolucao3">Paciente3</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<textarea name="evolucao" readonly>

</textarea>
<!--Jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select[name="nome_cliente"]').on('change', function () {
            var evolucao = $('select[name="nome_cliente"] > option:selected').data('evolucao');

            $('textarea[name="evolucao"]').text(evolucao);
        });

    })
</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pelo trecho de código foi exatamente o que precisava, com a chamada da variável evolucao dentro do select deu certinho meu codigo. TKS

Comment: De nada, se puder votar na resposta agradeço.